# How to iterate a list with string elements and append a specific value to another list if a specific conditional statement in the first list is true?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-in-loop

I am working in Google Colab. I have a list named `dir` with string elements. I want to create a new list in which i will append a specific number depending on whether a specific character sequence is found in the elements of the `dir` list.

Here is the code i wrote:

```
labels=[]

for value in dir:
  if '/River/' in dir:
    labels.append(1)
  elif '/HerbaceousVegetation/' in dir:
    labels.append(2)
  elif '/Highway/' in dir:
    labels.append(3)
  elif '/Residential/' in dir:
    labels.append(4)
  elif '/Industrial/' in dir:
    labels.append(5)
  elif '/AnnualCrop/' in dir:
    labels.append(6)
  elif '/Pasture/' in dir:
    labels.append(7)
  elif '/PermanentCrop/' in dir:
    labels.append(8)
  elif '/SeaLake/' in dir:
    labels.append(9)
  else:
    labels.append(10)
```

The result is the list `labels` which has the value 10 in each element. It seems that the conditional statement takes into account only the `else` statement.
How can i transform my code to take into account all the statements?

Comment: You could have made it concise by iterating  those strings using `enumerate` . If `labels` has 10 in all the values, it means that only the `else` part is being executed and it depends on what values are there in your `dir` variable.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (**show the value of *dir*, and the expected output for it**, and also the current one. If possible, give more examples). *dir* is a builtin name, use another one.

Comment: Just so you know `dir` is a python keyword. Also, you’re iterating over `dir` but you never make use of `value`. Shouldn’t the comparison be to `value` and not `dir` in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are checking is string in list `dir` not in the element of list `dir`. Change the if statements to `(el)if 'your_string' in value:` and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

1. `dir` already refers to the inbuilt function `dir()` and shouldn't be used as a variable.
2. You are checking if a certain string exists in the list, whereas you should be checking whether the string exists inside the elements of the list.

```
labels = []
l = [] #should be filled with your data replacing dir
for value in l:
  if '/River/' in value:
    labels.append(1)
  elif '/HerbaceousVegetation/' in value:
    labels.append(2)
  #all your cases
  else:
    labels.append(10)
```

Comment: I am working in Google Colab and as i see `dir` is not a keyword in Google Colab.